# Why when i create item of my linear layout my app is ruined

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout

## Why button delete ruined my app

So i built my app ToDo list in its one, i have MainActivity, which has toolbar and LinearLayout.

```
//MainActivity
package com.example.todolist

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var titleGot: String? = ""
    private var descriptionGot: String? = ""
    private lateinit var taskAdapter: TaskAdapter
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        initUI()
        init()
    }

    private fun init() {
        val tasks = ArrayList<Task>()
        taskAdapter = TaskAdapter(tasks)
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.taskRecyclerView)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.adapter = TaskAdapter(tasks = tasks)
    }

    private fun initUI() {
        findViewById<View>(R.id.toolbar_1_button_add).setOnClickListener {
            val myIntent = Intent(this, ForCreatingItemActivity::class.java)
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 100)
            Toast.makeText(this, "open", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        findViewById<View>(R.id.toolbar_1_button_settings).setOnClickListener { Toast.makeText(this, "settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
        findViewById<View>(R.id.toolbar_1_button_filter_list).setOnClickListener { Toast.makeText(this, "filter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
    }
    
    @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if(requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            titleGot = data.getStringExtra("title")
            descriptionGot = data.getStringExtra("description")

            if(titleGot != "" && descriptionGot != "")
            {
                taskAdapter.addTask(Task(taskAdapter.itemCount + 1,title =  titleGot.toString(),description = descriptionGot.toString()))
            }
        }

    }
}

data class Task( var id: Int, val title: String, val description: String, )

class TaskAdapter(private val tasks: MutableList<Task>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskAdapter.TaskViewHolder>() {

        class TaskViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
            val titleTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionTextView)
            val descriptionTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView)
            val idTextView : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idTextView)
//          val deleteButton: Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_1_button_delete)
        }

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TaskViewHolder {
            val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.task_item, parent, false)
            return TaskViewHolder(itemView)
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TaskViewHolder, position: Int) {
            val task = tasks[position]
            holder.titleTextView.text = task.title
            holder.descriptionTextView.text = task.description
            holder.idTextView.text = task.id.toString()
//          holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener { deleteTask(task,position) }
        }
        override fun getItemCount(): Int { return tasks.size }
    
        @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
        fun addTask(task: Task) {
            tasks.add(task)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
        private fun deleteTask(task: Task, position: Int) {
            tasks.remove(task)
            notifyItemRemoved(position)
        }
    }
```

[MainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQW48.png)

In toolbar we have button to add items in LinearLayout, this button send us to other activity where we write title and description for our item and this and if we click on button DONE then item add to LinearLayout.

```
package com.example.todolist

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.EditText

class ForCreatingItemActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_for_creating_item)
        initUI()
    }

    private fun initUI(){
        findViewById<View>(R.id.activity_2_Button_Exit).setOnClickListener{
            setResult(RESULT_OK,intent)
            finish() }
        findViewById<View>(R.id.activity_2_Button_Check).setOnClickListener{
            val title : EditText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.activity_2_Title)
            val description : EditText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.activity_2_Description)
            intent.putExtra("title",title.text.toString())
            intent.putExtra("description",description.text.toString())
            setResult(RESULT_OK,intent)
            finish()
        }
    }
}
```

[Activity for creating items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTt9x.png)

Item of linear layout contains ID,title,description,button for deleting.Task contains id,title,description.
[item of linear layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HgWW.png)

So come back to the problem now in code of mainactivity string with button delete is commented out in TaskViewHolder and onBindViewHolder without this code the app works correctly therefore items show on linear layout but we can't delete them. And if we remove comments then app is ruined on clicking DONE button. So what i need to do to app keeps working correctly?

Comment: What does "ruined" mean here? Is it crashing? If so post the stacktrace from the logs (the error message and the lines below showing what led up to the crash)

Comment: ahahha oh bro thanks i understood, my error was that i casted app.compat.view to button and that isnt correct. thanks